# Geoxml3 groundOverlay zIndex

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geoxml3

Is there a way to change the zIndex of a groundOverlay?

With Geoxml3 I am parsing two KML files, one of them contains a polygon and the other one contains a groundOverlay. Everythings goes perfect except for the fact that i want my groundOverlay OVER the polygon, because now the groundOverlay appears behind the polygon.

Update:
This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Geoxml3</title>
<style>
    html{height:100%;}
    body{height:100%;margin:0px;}
    #map_canvas{height: 90%;width: 90%;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ProjectedOverlay.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geoXml=null, map=null;

function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.397, -100.644),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
        map: map,
        zoom: true,
        createOverlay: addMyOverlay
    });

    geoXml.parse(['groundOverlay.kml','polygon.kml']);

    function addMyOverlay(placemark,doc){
        //How to change the the GroundOverlay zIndex
        var groundOverlay = geoXml.createOverlay(placemark);
        return groundOverlay;
    };
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The test is here:
http://jorgeluisperez.260mb.net/geoxml/

Comment: What does your existing code look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to specify `zIndex` for `GroundOverlay` once the map is loaded:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
      var overlayDiv = document.getElementById(groundOverlay.id_);
      overlayDiv.style.zIndex = '999';
      console.log(overlayDiv);
});
```

> Note: `groundOverlay` should be accessible from event

**Working example: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ef7b5AIroNinL2XuRBmZ?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

The `ProjectedOverlay` class which is used to render GroundOverlays in [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) attaches the overlays to the [overlayLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapPanes).  That is the same pane in which polygons are rendered.  The OverlayView class doesn't support zIndex, and the zIndex supported by Polygons specifically states it is only good between "polys".  It is possible that the order of adding the Polygons vs. the GroundOverlays might change that, but [a quick test](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_GroundOverlay_zIndex_ordered.html) didn't work.  You could modify the ProjectedOverlay code to append the overlay to a pane above the overlayLayer.

from [the documentation on MapPanes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapPanes):

This object contains the DOM elements in which overlays are rendered. They are listed below with 'Pane 0' at the bottom and 'Pane 4' at the top.

Properties

- floatPane | This pane contains the info window. It is above all map overlays. (Pane 4).
- mapPane | This pane is the lowest pane and is above the tiles. It may not receive DOM events. (Pane 0).
- markerLayer | This pane contains markers. It may not receive DOM events. (Pane 2).
- overlayLayer | This pane contains polylines, polygons, ground overlays and tile layer overlays. It may not receive DOM events. (Pane 1).
- overlayMouseTarget | This pane contains elements that receive DOM events. (Pane 3).